# Glitch while Styling Android Overflow Menu

Tags: android, menu, styles, overflow

After several hours of research, try and fail, I have managed to Style and Customize the Toolbar Popup Menu, but I'm having a weird glitch.
[image: Android Glitch]

As You can see, when I click on the popup menu, it appears styled and all, but If I press an item the background gets highlighted but the text do not. Why is this happening? Can this be corrected? Or is it another mighty bug of Android?

Thanks